# How do I avoid multiple queries with :include in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I do this

```
post = Post.find_by_id(post_id, :include => :comments)
```

two queries are performed (one for post data and and another for the post's comments). Then when I do post.comments, another query is not performed because data is already cached.

Is there a way to do just one query and still access the comments via post.comments?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. I tried using an outer join on comments. That does execute only one query, but the result is not cached. So, when I call `post.comments` it does executes another query. I'd be interested if someone else comes up with an answer for this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, there is not. This is the intended behavior of `:include`, since the `JOIN` approach ultimately comes out to be inefficient.

For example, consider the following scenario: the `Post` model has 3 fields that you need to select, 2 fields for `Comment`, and this particular post has 100 comments. Rails *could* run a single `JOIN` query along the lines of:

```
SELECT post.id, post.title, post.author_id, comment.id, comment.body
FROM posts
INNER JOIN comments ON comment.post_id = post.id
WHERE post.id = 1
```

This would return the following table of results:

```
 post.id | post.title | post.author_id | comment.id | comment.body
---------+------------+----------------+------------+--------------
       1 | Hello!     |              1 |          1 | First!
       1 | Hello!     |              1 |          2 | Second!
       1 | Hello!     |              1 |          3 | Third!
       1 | Hello!     |              1 |          4 | Fourth!
...96 more...
```

You can see the problem already. The single-query `JOIN` approach, though it returns the data you need, returns it redundantly. When the database server sends the result set to Rails, it will send the post's ID, title, and author ID 100 times each. Now, suppose that the `Post` had 10 fields you were interested in, 8 of which were text blocks. Eww. That's a lot of data. Transferring data from the database to Rails *does* take work on both sides, both in CPU cycles and RAM, so minimizing that data transfer is important for making the app run faster and leaner.

The Rails devs crunched the numbers, and most applications run better when using multiple queries that only fetch each bit of data once rather than one query that has the potential to get hugely redundant.

Of course, there comes a time in every developer's life when a join is necessary in order to run complex conditions, and that can be achieved by replacing `:include` with `:joins`. For prefetching relationships, however, the approach Rails takes in `:include` is much better for performance.

Comment: Hey Matchu, it seems like the :joins approach would be for efficient than :include given a has_one relationship. Is this true, or should I carry on with :include?

Comment: @rayban: interesting. I'd suspect that'd work well, but I don't know off the top of my head whether or not `:joins` properly instantiates the other objects or if it ends up firing another query for each (even though it really shouldn't). Might be worth running your own benchmark to find out :/

Answer (score 5):

If you use [this behaviour](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) of eagerly-loaded associations, you'll get a single (and efficient) query.

Here is an example:

- Say you have the following model (where `:user` is the foreign reference):

  ```
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
  end
  ```
- Then executing this (**note**: the `where` part is crucial as it tricks Rails to produce that single query):

  ```
  @items = Item.includes(:user).where("users.id IS NOT NULL").all
  ```

  will result in a single SQL query (the syntax below is that of PostgreSQL):

```sql
    SELECT "items"."id" AS t0_r0, "items"."user_id" AS t0_r1, 
            "items"."name" AS t0_r2, "items"."created_at" AS t0_r3,
            "items"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "users"."id" AS t1_r0, 
            "users"."email" AS t1_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t1_r4, 
            "users"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 
    FROM "measurements" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "items"."user_id" 
    WHERE (users.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: It *works*, but you really shouldn't do it. When conditions are necessary, use conditions. When they're not, trust the default Rails behavior. It's been very closely scrutinized by very clever people.

Comment: Yes, good point. But this does make me interested in what lies behind the decisions they made. I think an explanation would be welcome. I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719607/how-to-eagerly-load-the-single-foreign-reference-efficiently-with-activerecords) which should hopefully clear it out.