# How do I use "includes" in a Rails 3 AREL statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I am trying to see the SQL behind and AREL statement:

```
Brand.where(:subdomain => "coke").includes(:products).to_sql
```

brand has_many products, and product belongs_to brand.

However, the above statement yields only:

```
"SELECT `brands`.* FROM `brands` WHERE `brands`.`subdomain` = 'coke'"
```

Why don't I see the information for the `products` table in the SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use an `includes` statement, Rails will generate a separate query per table (so if you include 2 other tables, there will be 3 queries total).

You can use a `joins` statement instead and it will lump it all into one query, however you may experience a performance hit. Also, if any of your `where(...)` conditions query against the included table, it will be lumped into one query.

See [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246826/how-do-i-avoid-multiple-queries-with-include-in-rails) for more information on Rails' behavior.

Comment: Uh, it won't generate a separate query per table if there's a condition in the query to reference that table. Instead, it will use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a single query.

Comment: That's what I said... "if any of your conditions query against the included table, it will be lumped into one query [instead of running the multiple queries]"

Comment: Ahhhh, pointing me at that other question really brought it home for me Dylan. If it was doing a JOIN off the "includes", it would bring back redundant data for the main AR object. Makes perfect sense, thanks!