# Using LEFT OUTER JOIN to eager load associations without conditions?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We have a model with a has_one association set up:

```
class User
  has_one :shirt

class Shirt
  belongs_to :user
```

At the moment we can add `.includes(:shirt)` when retrieving a limited array of Users and it will conduct two SQL queries as expected.

The problem for us is that the query to load the pages is doing this:

```
SELECT "shirt".* FROM "shirts" WHERE "shirt"."user_id" IN (2147521, 2147522 ... )
```

When retrieving, say, 50 Users and Shirts this isn't very performant for us. Our users and shirts tables are big. We're noticing a big speed increase by forcing Rails to use an INNER JOIN instead by doing:

```
User.where( ... ).joins(:shirts).includes(:shirts).limit(50)
```

Unfortunately this only returns users that have shirts. We need to be able to return a limited array of users whether they have an associated shirt or not.

Is there a way to force Rails to eager load associated objects using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of the two-query method that is the default?

### Edit

By adding a `where` clause that returns true whether a value on the associated object is null or not. It doesn't seem to mind if there's no associated object, at least on Postgres.

```
User.where( ... ).includes(:shirt).where("shirts.created_at IS NULL OR shirts.created_at IS NOT NULL")
```

This solves the problem but it's hardly ideal, isn't there a way to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of the default two-query approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246826/how-do-i-avoid-multiple-queries-with-include-in-rails), the 2-query approach is thought to be faster for most cases (although not necessarily so for a one-to-one relationship as you have it).  If you want to force Rails to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, you can do this by adding a meaningless filter on the associated table:

```
User.where( ... ).
     includes(:shirts).
     where("shirts.id IS NULL OR shirts.id = shirts.id").
     limit(50)
```

Comment: Snap, literally just sussed this and edited the post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one-to-one association, like in your example above, you can use `eager_load` method like so : `User.eager_load(:shirt)`, it will use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so you will be able to use `user.shirt` with only 1 query, but I am not sure if its something new for rails 4 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Applying to Rails4:

```
User.where( ... ).includes(:shirts).references(:shirts)
```

or

```
User.where( ... ).eager_load(:shirts)
```

will force `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather separate query